# Hive window function

Tags: sql, date, hive

I have data in below format and i need to generate flag_date column based on flag column value changes.

```
login_date      id      flag       flag_date   
5/1/2018        100     Y            NULL 
5/2/2018        100     Y            NULL
5/3/2018        100     N          5/3/2018
5/4/2018        100     N          5/3/2018
5/5/2018        100     Y          5/3/2018
5/6/2018        100     Y          5/3/2018
5/7/2018        100     N          5/7/2018
5/8/2018        100     Y          5/7/2018
5/9/2018        100     Y          5/7/2018
5/10/2018       100     N          5/10/2018
```

Initially flag_date value will be null, but when flag changes from Y to N, flag_date will get populated and the value will continue till next Y to N change. Please help.

Comment: Dates are not in sort-able format

Comment: sorry.. didnt get you. we can change format right?

Comment: Correct format is 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: ok.. i can get that format. thats not an issue

Answer (score 0):

You problem seems to be easy with window functions, but it is tricky. There are dependencies with flags wrt to prior records and using the first value when there are consecutive Y/N s.

1. From t1, we are taking prior_flag and prior_flag_dt i.e fg_dt
2. From t2, we are sorting out the consecutive N/Y fg_dt2
3. In t3, we are again looking back the sorted out fg_dt2. Now the first record in the consecutive  Y/N will have the correct value that needs to be used for the next Y/N
4. In the final query, you get the results.

Check this out:

```
> create table hr02 ( login_date date, id int, flag string, flag_date date );

> insert into hr02 
select '2018-05-01', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all 
select '2018-05-02', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-03', 100, 'N', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-04', 100, 'N', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-05', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-06', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-07', 100, 'N', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-08', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-09', 100, 'Y', NULL
union all
select '2018-05-10', 100, 'N', NULL ;


> with t1 as ( select login_date, id, flag, lag(flag) over(order by login_date) as prior_flag, case when flag='Y' then lag(login_date) over(order by login_date)  else login_date end as fg_dt from hr02),
 t2 as ( select login_date, id, flag, prior_flag, fg_dt, case when flag='Y' then lag(fg_dt) over(order by login_date) when flag='N'  and prior_flag='N' then lag(fg_dt) over(order by login_date) else login_date end as fg_dt2 from t1 ),
 t3 as ( select login_date, id, flag, prior_flag, fg_dt, fg_dt2, case when flag='Y' and prior_flag='N' then lag(fg_dt2) over(order by login_date) when flag='N'  and prior_flag='N' then lag(fg_dt) over(order by login_date) else fg_dt2 end as fg_dt3  from t2)
 select login_date, id, flag, prior_flag, fg_dt, fg_dt2, fg_dt3, case when flag='Y' and prior_flag='Y' then lag(fg_dt3) over(order by login_date) else fg_dt3 end fg_dt4 from t3 ;


+-------------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--+
| login_date  |  id  | flag  | prior_flag  |    fg_dt    |   fg_dt2    |   fg_dt3    |   fg_dt4    |
+-------------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--+
| 2018-05-01  | 100  | Y     | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        |
| 2018-05-02  | 100  | Y     | Y           | 2018-05-01  | NULL        | NULL        | NULL        |
| 2018-05-03  | 100  | N     | Y           | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  |
| 2018-05-04  | 100  | N     | N           | 2018-05-04  | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  |
| 2018-05-05  | 100  | Y     | N           | 2018-05-04  | 2018-05-04  | 2018-05-03  | 2018-05-03  |
| 2018-05-06  | 100  | Y     | Y           | 2018-05-05  | 2018-05-04  | 2018-05-04  | 2018-05-03  |
| 2018-05-07  | 100  | N     | Y           | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  |
| 2018-05-08  | 100  | Y     | N           | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  |
| 2018-05-09  | 100  | Y     | Y           | 2018-05-08  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  | 2018-05-07  |
| 2018-05-10  | 100  | N     | Y           | 2018-05-10  | 2018-05-10  | 2018-05-10  | 2018-05-10  |
+-------------+------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--+
```